# Custom Labels Data retrieval with translations

Tags: custom, data-export

I am having some CustomLabels in my DeveloperEdition with translations, Is there any possibilities to export all labels in excel sheet using tools? (Ex:Like as DataLoader)

Thanks
Venkatsforce

Answer (score 4):

Custom labels are metadata. Normal access through data loader would be limited.

Either you can access it through the IDE, or some other metadata tool.

Or, you can turn on Translation Workbench, and use the export feature there. You can enable the Translation Workbench for only the primary language of your org. This export will include *all* labels, not just your custom ones.

Enable translation workbench through setup, then you can go to Export and perform your export.

[image]

This will produce a two column file you can then open with Excel (although you will need to start your import around the place where you see the line:

# KEY    LABEL

```
ButtonOrLink.Account.Billing    Billing
ButtonOrLink.Account.Billing_WarehouseSchema    Billing
ButtonOrLink.Campaign.ViewCampaignInfluenceReport   View Campaign Influence Report
...
```

For me this was around line 17.

Then look toward the bottom, your custom labels will look like this:

```
CustomLabel.My_Label    My Label
CustomLabel.That_Label  That Label
CustomLabel.This_Label  This Label
```

Comment: Thanks for your Comment @Peter, I tried like this way but my Excelsheet didn't seperate the columns like Labels & Value how to seperate the columns like this when we are exporting the Labels from Salesforce. Am having more number of labels like more than 500.                                                                                                                    "Labels                                 Value                                                                   CustomLabel.My_Label    My Label
CustomLabel.That_Label  That Label
CustomLabel.This_Label  This Label"

Comment: Strange. I'm importing as Tab delimited and it works fine using Excel 2011 on Mac. You might need to trim off all the header text (about the first 16 lines of the file) then try again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can do that using data loader. But you can extract the custom labels in XML format using Eclipse.

> Assuming that your only requirement is to have your custom labels in excel.

1. Open eclipse, expand your org nod > **src** nod > Labels > **Custom Labels.labels**
2. This file will be in xml format, copy xml and paste this into notepad
3. Save to any location on your machine as XML format.
4. Open MS - Excel
5. Goto Data > "From Other Source" > "From XML data import", and then point to the file saved in step3. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Mahmood Butt, I tried as per your 5th steps but i am getting the xml replica in my excel sheet. I need a xml values as Columns in Excel sheet Labels & values in seperate columns like example Xml : <label>Custom_FirstName</label>
          <name>Firstname</name>
Excel sheet columns :  "Labels -- Custom_FirstName , name -- Firstname"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following SFDX command:

```
sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id, ExternalStringId, ExternalString.MasterLabel, ExternalString.Value, Value, Language FROM ExternalStringLocalization" -t -u Your_Orgs_Name -r csv > your_files_name.csv
```

whereas:

-q provides the query string

-t stands for Tooling API

-u provides the alias of the org

-r provides the requested format (human/csv/json)

">" provides the file in which you want to save the sheet